# How can I get the difference in minutes between two dates and hours?

Tags: c

The date format is `dd-mm-yyyy` (it's the format here in Portugal), and the hour is `hh:mm`. My code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct DateTime {
    int day, month, year, hour, minute;
};

// Function to convert date and time to minutes since midnight
int minutes_since_midnight(struct DateTime dt) {
    return dt.hour * 60 + dt.minute;
}

// Function to calculate time difference
int calculate_time_difference(char date_in[], char time_in[], char date_out[], char time_out[]) {
    struct DateTime dt1, dt2;
    sscanf(date_in, "%d-%d-%d", &dt1.day, &dt1.month, &dt1.year);
    sscanf(time_in, "%d:%d", &dt1.hour, &dt1.minute);
    sscanf(date_out, "%d-%d-%d", &dt2.day, &dt2.month, &dt2.year);
    sscanf(time_out, "%d:%d", &dt2.hour, &dt2.minute);

    // Convert date and time to minutes since midnight
    int minutes1 = minutes_since_midnight(dt1);
    int minutes2 = minutes_since_midnight(dt2);

    // Calculate total difference in minutes
    int time_difference = abs(minutes2 - minutes1);

    // Calculate day difference in minutes
    int day_difference = dt2.day - dt1.day;

    // If the date of departure is before the date of arrival, adjust the day difference
    if (day_difference < 0) {
        // Add a full day of minutes
        day_difference += 1;
        // Add the remaining hours of the departure day
        time_difference += (24 - dt1.hour) * 60 + (60 - dt1.minute);
        // Add the hours of the arrival day
        time_difference += dt2.hour * 60 + dt2.minute;
    } else {
        // If the date of departure is after the date of arrival, just add the remaining minutes
        time_difference += day_difference * 24 * 60;
    }

    return time_difference;
}

int main() {
    int time_diff = calculate_time_difference("01-01-2024", "19:05", "02-01-2024", "9:05");
    printf("Time difference->%i\n", time_diff);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see from the example in `main`, in the case where input 1 = `"01-01-2024", "19:05"` and input 2 = `"02-01-2024", "9:05"` the time difference in minutes should be `840` (14 hours * 60 minutes). The code when I run it says: `Time difference->2040`. How can I fix this?

Ignore leap years for this example.

Comment: Why are you not using the standard C functions for this?

Comment: I cannot, this is a challenge for my software engineering degree , and I cannot use libraries any other than those I'm using

Comment: `// If the date of departure is after...` Not really... What if `day_difference == 0` or `day_difference == 1`... Don't calculate `time_difference` so early, then add to it. No shortcuts... There are 3 different situations, given the hint that _departure_ and _arrival_ may be -1,0 or 0,0 or 1,0...

Comment: @baptzera I see... Then convert both dates to minutes since "day 0" and then take the difference between those. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/3Yxdosd9s) - Note that once you pass a month boundary, it's going to get tricky. You need to deal with different lengths of the months and leap years etc.

Comment: Write you own function to convert date-time to seconds since some epoch. Don't mix it with the data input from strings, but write one function for each. There's no mention of leap years in the code. *Oh! They are short journeys.* Hm, from Feb 28 to Mar 1?

Comment: btw I forgot to mention , in this example, my professor told us there is no leap years

Comment: _Side note:_ Passing a `struct` by _value_ is almost never done. With that, you have to push (onto the stack) the entire contents of the `struct`. To see why, add `int data[10000000];` to your struct definition. Most structs are passed by _reference_ (i.e. by passing a _pointer_ to the struct). Better signature for your function: `int minutes_since_midnight(const struct DateTime *dt)`

Comment: Is `DateTime.month` a value between 1-12 or 0-11?

Comment: You're _not_ handling the difference in months [let alone the years]. For example, `Jan 05` to `Feb 05` is 31 days. But, `Feb 05` to `Mar 05` is 28 days. You need a table of the number of days in a month (e.g.) `int days_per_mon[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };`

Comment: The VG suggestion by @CraigEstey could be improved by a table of _cumulative_ values. For "05Jan" the **day of year** is 5+0. The DOY for "07Feb" is 7+31. DOY for "03Mar" is 3+59... Do you see where this is going? Any two _consecutive_ dates will differ by `abs(dayOfYear1-dayOfYear2)`... The next issue is _New Years_... Have fun! (With this simplification, even accounting for Leap Years would be a trivial extension.)

Comment: @Fe2O3 You mean (e.g.): `int julian_offset[12]; julian_offset[0] = 0; for (int imon = 1; imon < 12; ++imon) julian_offset[imon] = julian_offset[imon - 1] + days_per_month[imon - 1];`? ;-)

Comment: The point about not using standard library time functions should be in the question not a comment, so that no one wastes their time with a valid answer to an apparently incomplete question.  Comments are not part of teh question which must _stand alone_.

Comment: @CraigEstey Yes. `:-)` ... but _pre-computed_... A 'no-too-difficult' macro _chain_ would make the intent obvious to the reader (for checking), yet have the compiler do the numeric grunt work... `:-)`...

Comment: @CraigEstey Presuming 4-byte `int`, the 12 element array could be filled with **MoY** (cumulative minutes passed _so far_ at the start of each new month.) Why not? `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no date comes before Jan 1, 1970 (standard epoch time).  This should suffice. And if you do have pre-1970 dates, change the `int year = 1970` statement below to have an initial value of `1`.

The code below basically counts up the number of seconds from 1/1/1970 at midnight accounting for leap years as it goes.

Below assumes a basic understanding that:

- Leap years have 366 days. Non leap-years have 365 days
- Leap years usually occur on years divisible by 4, but not on years divisible by 100 unless also divisible by 400 (the year 2000 is a leap year, but the year 2100 will not).
- That the `DateTime` struct will never have negative numbers, months less than 1 or greater than 12.  Hours are assumed to be between 0-23 (military time). Minutes are a value between 0-59.
- Months are assumed to be numbered between 1-12
- Same time zone for comparing differences.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

struct DateTime {
    int day, month, year, hour, minute;
};

const int SECONDS_IN_DAY = 86400;

int isLeapYear(int year) {
    if (year % 4) return 0;
    if (year % 400 == 0) return 1;
    if (year % 100 == 0) return 0;
    return 1;
}

int getDaysInYear(int year) {
    return isLeapYear(year) ? 366 : 365;
}

int64_t seconds_since_epoch(const struct DateTime* dt) {
    size_t days_in_month[13] = { 0, 31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 };
    int year = 1970;
    int month = 1;
    int day = 1;
    int64_t total = 0;

    while (year < dt->year) {
        total += getDaysInYear(year) * SECONDS_IN_DAY;
        year++;
    }

    if (isLeapYear(year)) {
        days_in_month[2] = 29;
    }

    while (month < dt->month) {
        total += days_in_month[month] * SECONDS_IN_DAY;
        month++;
    }

    total += (dt->day - day) * SECONDS_IN_DAY;
    total += 60 * 60 * dt->hour; // hours to seconds
    total += 60 * dt->minute;    // minutes to seconds
    return total;
}

// Function to calculate time difference
int calculate_time_difference(char date_in[], char time_in[], char date_out[], char time_out[]) {
    struct DateTime dt1, dt2;
    sscanf(date_in, "%d-%d-%d", &dt1.day, &dt1.month, &dt1.year);
    sscanf(time_in, "%d:%d", &dt1.hour, &dt1.minute);
    sscanf(date_out, "%d-%d-%d", &dt2.day, &dt2.month, &dt2.year);
    sscanf(time_out, "%d:%d", &dt2.hour, &dt2.minute);

    // Convert date and time to seconds since epoch
    int64_t seconds1 = seconds_since_epoch(&dt1);
    int64_t seconds2 = seconds_since_epoch(&dt2);

    auto difference_in_seconds = abs(seconds1 - seconds2);
    int difference_in_minutes = difference_in_seconds / 60;
    return difference_in_minutes;
}

int main() {
    int time_diff = calculate_time_difference("01-01-2024", "19:05", "02-01-2024", "9:05");
    printf("Time difference->%i\n", time_diff);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Providing the OP with completion of their homework assignment is considered a bad idea. If I were grading this _submission_, I'd take a few marks off for using a global variable... And for a few unnecessary `#include`s, too.

Comment: @Fe2O3 - Global variable?

Comment: What is the scope of `const int SECONDS_IN_DAY = 86400;`?

Comment: Global, yes.  However, a *constant* (and declared as such), and perfectly acceptable.

Comment: AND, since this answer attempts to demonstrate prowess (instead of coaching the OP toward finding their own solution, thereby actually learning), you should understand, too, that `static size_t days_in_month[13]` would not require reloading the array each time `seconds_since_epoch()` is invoked... "_Acceptable_" is in the eyes of the beholder... Explain how this answer differs from what ChatGPT might offer...

Comment: `seconds_since_epoch( &dt1, min( dt1.year, dt2.year ) );` would obviate the problem of the code hard-wiring an _epoch year_ (and reduce the number of iterations required counting up to the target year...) Jus' sayin'...

Comment: Refer to my comment (below the OP's question) suggesting **cumulative** values be used to initialise `days_in_month[]`... More unnecessary iterations can be eliminated (tallying days-per-month for each month preceding the target)...

Comment: @Fe2O3 - there's all kinds of micro-optimizations that can be applied.  But I stand by my answer. I wasn't aware this was a homework assignment, else I might have just given hints.

Comment: this is not a homework assignment. This is a challenge the teacher gave us just for fun. But I thank you for not spoiling it

Comment: @selbie In light of your SO rep, it surprises me that the Q didn't _smell_ to you of being homework (or a Codewarriors et.al. exercise.) Just me commenting on what you've posted as an answer. Note: If the actual dates used were from another era (eg: WWII), improving on `1` as the epoch year ranks a little higher than a mere *micro-optimisation*...

Answer (score 1):

A "C" approach could use functions from `<time.h>`.

OP comments, but not in the question, "I cannot, this is a challenge for my software engineering degree , and I cannot use libraries any other than those I'm using".  Well you can use those functions to check your work.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

// Return error flag
bool calculate_time_difference_ref(double *diff_min, //
    const char date_in[], const char time_in[], //
    const char date_out[], const char time_out[]) {
  struct tm dt1 = { .tm_isdst = -1 };
  struct tm dt2 = { .tm_isdst = -1 };
  if (sscanf(date_in,  "%d-%d-%d", &dt1.tm_mday, &dt1.tm_mon, &dt1.tm_year) != 3) return true;
  if (sscanf(time_in,  "%d:%d", &dt1.tm_hour, &dt1.tm_min) != 2) return true;
  if (sscanf(date_out, "%d-%d-%d", &dt2.tm_mday, &dt2.tm_mon, &dt2.tm_year) != 3) return true;
  if (sscanf(time_out, "%d:%d", &dt2.tm_hour, &dt2.tm_min) != 2) return true;

  time_t t_in = mktime(&dt1);
  time_t t_out = mktime(&dt2);
  if (t_in == -1 || t_out == -1) return true;
  *diff_min = difftime(t_in, t_out)/60.0;  // Difference in minutes
  return false;
}
```

Note the above takes into account *daylight savings time*.

Use `struct tm dt1 = { .tm_isdst = 0 };` to assume standard time.

Comment: Hi there! Request: You posted a marvellous, non-iterating Gregorian "Date to Days-Since-Epoch" function some time ago (that even accounted for leap years). Perhaps adding (to this answer) a link to that posting would spread knowledge of that very(!) useful marvel a bit wider. Cheers! `:-)`